# How to merge the 2 y axis trend lines into 1, unable to use 'dual axis'

Tags: tableau-api

The image shows the trend of particular data from Sept 17 to May 18

[image]

How to merge the 2 y axis trend lines into 1, so that I have 1 single trend line from Sept 17 to May 18 (unable to use 'dual axis')

Comment: can you share workbook

Answer (score 0):

Do the following, create a calculated field with this:

```
ZN([measure1]) + ZN([measure2])
```

Now instead of dragging each measure in, just drag this calculated field, and then drag the same calculated field into colors.

If I understood what your problem is, that should sort you out. I'm assuming you have two different measures that you need to represent on the same graph.

If your problem is not due to measures but to the time field then your solution will have to be different, but let me know please